# Tratamento de valores retornados na query

Tags: mysql, query

Preciso "tratar" o retorno de uma SELECT da seguinte forma:
- valor gravado no banco: `www.dominio.com.br` ou `www.dominio.com`
- valor tratado na pagina: `dominio`;

Ou seja, preciso que a `query` "retire" o que estiver antes do nome do domínio e depois dele.

É bem simples tirar uma das partes(antes e depois), mas as duas deu nó, como fazer isto na query?

Comment: Caso você queira usar a "edição" diretamente no SQL, você pode tentar o seguinte: `SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(seu_campo, '.', 2), '.', -1) as dominio FROM sua_tabela`, só substituir os nomes sugestivos pelos seus valores. Como você não forneceu mais detalhes da linguagem usada, não há como fornecer outra forma.

Comment: Opa, exatamente isso que eu preciso, o "seu_campo" vou trocar aqui por ORIGEM_PESSOA, só que o DOMINIO é um campo da tabela e pode ter N valores (dominioX, dominioZZ, etc.). Como posso fazer? Valeu @RafaelWithoeft

Comment: O `as dominio` é somente um alias, pode ser trocado pelo nome que desejar... era isso que estava com dúvidas? O campo `ORIGEM_PESSOA` é o descrito na sua pergunta que possui o valor `www.dominio.com.br` ?

Comment: SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(origem_pessoa, '.', 2), '.', -1) FROM pessoa, assim foi como ficou o que eu preciso, desta forma tá retornando só o domínio sem os www, .com ou outro.  Valeu!!  @RafaelWithoeft

Comment: Então funcionou certinho? :)

Comment: Sim! Resolvido muito obrigado (aliás como eu marco RESOLVIDO aqui no Stack?)

Comment: Só em respostas... posso montar uma para você

Comment: Por favor desde que você (ou quem ajudou) seja "condecorado" heheh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso você queira usar a "formatação" diretamente no `SQL`, você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
 SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(seu_campo, '.', 2), '.', -1) as dominio FROM sua_tabela
```

Só substituir os nomes sugestivos pelos seus valores. Como você não forneceu mais detalhes da linguagem usada, não há como fornecer outra forma.

---

A utilização do `SUBSTRING_INDEX` é bastante simples.
Você fornece uma string, um delimitador e a quantidade(count).

No seu caso, vamos pegar como base o valor `www.dominio.com.br`, seguem os exemplos:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.dominio.com.br', '.', 2) => 'www.dominio';
//Números positivos, tudo o que estiver a esquerda do "delimitador final" (contando da esquerda) é retornado.

SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.dominio.com.br', '.', -2) => 'com.br';
//Números negativos, tudo o que estiver a direita do "delimitador final" (contando da direita) é retornado
```

Tendo os resultados acima, vamos a aplicação do seu caso:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.dominio.com.br', '.', 2), '.', -1) => 'dominio';
```

Como sabemos que a primeira expressão a ser executada irá retornar `www.dominio`, usamos novamente a expressão e pegamos a primeira posição a direita (para isso usamos o valor negativo -1), que no caso retorna `dominio`.

Espero ter sido claro na explicação. Qualquer dúvida ou sugestão de melhoria para a resposta, fique a vontade em solicitar.

**Fontes/Referências:**

[Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two)
[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)